# How to drop constraints in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query in SQL:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id('[FK_states_list]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsForeignKey') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [custom_table] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_states_list] ;
```

How can I write this query in Postgres?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It seems you want to drop the constraint, only if it exists.

In Postgres you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE custom_table 
  DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS fk_states_list;
```

You can also make sure the table exists:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS custom_table 
  DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS fk_states_list;
```

Comment: This is why PostgreSQL is the best. You cannot do IF EXISTS in MySQL. What a sad thing.